# Microsoft Bot framework not working as expected

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I am developing one chat bot using Microsoft Bot Framework in NodeJs. Most of the time it works perfectly as expected. But sometimes when I am communicating with the bot, I'm not getting the response immediately. After entering the second question it is responding both the questions continuously. Help me to fix this issue. Should I do something on the server side?

```
dialog.matches('help',[
    function (session, args, next) {builder.Prompts.choice(session, "I can help you to shop products for your lifestyle. You can buy from the following categories.", "Computer|TV|See more", { listStyle: builder.ListStyle["list"] });

    },
    function (session, results) {
        if (results.response.entity=='TV') {
            session.send("Wow. That sounds interesting one. We have many %s models. Ask me question like \"I want to buy black color Samsung LED Tv .\"", results.response.entity);
            session.endDialog();
        }else{
            session.send("Selected category is expected soon.");
            session.endDialog();
        }           
    }]);
```

Comment: First you should post some of your code so we can see what you've already tried

Comment: I have added some code sample in the question

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the `Session.sendBatch` method to force queued messages to be delivered immediately.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you encountered a known problem with the Web Chat control. See https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/965 for reference. If this is the case, then the behaviour you described should have resolved in the meantime with the update 5 days ago.

Can you please re-test and confirm if the problem persists?